# Can I count Phing target invocation/execution?

Tags: phing

I'm currently working on a parallel multi-node deploy script using Phing and need to know for a specific target, if it has already been invoked.

The target list length varies on node type (let's say staging has three servers and production ten) and we already have parallel execution of targets in place. After all machines have been deployed, I need to update the (single) database server. Is there a way to check for that specific target that it has not been invoked/executed by another thread?

Example:

```
    <target name="run">
      <property name="host" value="10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, etc..."/>
      <parallelforeach list="${host}" param="host" target="execDeploy" delimiter=", "/>
    </target>

    <target name="execDeploy">
      <!-- do some deploy -->
      <phincall name="execOnce"/>
    </target>

    <!-- update DB -->
    <target name="execOnce"/>
```

Is there a way to do this?

**edit**

I could just add the first IP address to my build.properties, but that's not an elegant solution.

*Note:* The database is updated through specific code (deployed on each server) through one of the servers, not directly.

Comment: I used the easy way out by adding target "execOnce" after "run" in the depends attribute of the main target "deploy". This way we deploy the database changes after all parallel deploys have been run.

Although this fixes the immediate need of counting invocation times, I'm still curious if there is a way, so please let me know.